# How to add custom basemap to QGIS with missing tiles

Tags: qgis, basemap, amazon-web-services, s3

I am new to GIS. I have a custom basemap in S3 and I'm trying to import it into QGIS. It's timing out on some tiles that do not exist in my map:

> WARNING Network request s3://mybucket/14/4384/6146.jpg timed out

I dont have these tiles so I would QGIS to just ignore them, is there a way to do that?